# FireFox-OS / Google Maps V3 : Test on real phone "google is not defined"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, firefox-os

I'm writing an application for Firefox OS and i want to integrate a Google Maps V3

The problem is that If want to try my code with a real device, the map is not show due to "google is not defined".

I search and find this anwser : [Firefox OS CSP restrictions on privileged apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789009/firefox-os-csp-restrictions-on-privileged-apps) And the awnser leads me to think that If i don't submit my application to the marketplace, I could not try my code with a real device... I have to use a simulator for testing that.... Am I right ?

Is there any workaround for testing the code ? Because i find that it is realy strange to valid a code that you are developping for testing a map ... ?

A thing that is pretty weird to is that this project https://github.com/abhishekvp/Anchor-n-Explore seems to work very well on my phone...

Here is the code I write :

index.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true"></script>
```

And after I'm using the simple code for the hello world tutorial.

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem testing on a real device if it's working on the simulator. The problem should be elsewhere, but it's hard to say without more code.

Comment: You could my code here : https://github.com/binomed/CineShowTimeAngular, for more information, the index.html : https://github.com/binomed/CineShowTimeAngular/blob/master/src/main/html/index.html

The map class  (it's angular JS) : https://github.com/binomed/CineShowTimeAngular/blob/master/src/main/javascript/components/map.js and https://github.com/binomed/CineShowTimeAngular/blob/master/src/main/html/partials/components/map.html

Answer (score 1):

<del>MDN says ["As of Gecko 15.0, Content Security Policy no longer has any default restrictions"]. If your app works on a simulator, you can [push it to device] and it should work.</del>
[The CSP policy of FirefoxOS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Apps/Security#Default_CSP_policy) doesn't allow privileged apps to load external Javascript files. [This tutorial](https://blog.stackmob.com/2013/10/building-a-photo-sharing-app-for-firefox-os/) uses iframe.

1. create a separate html file which loads google map libs, and put it on a server.
2. place iframe in a html file of FirefoxOS privileged app.
3. It's possible to draw something on the map with postMessage.

   var mapIframe = document.getElementById('mapIframe');
   mapIframe.contentWindow.postMessage("CommandToDrawSomething", '*');

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any map, even with the simulator, in your application, but I'm sure it's a loading problem (you try to use the map before it's loaded) as the script is a loader, not the script itself. You should load it asynchronously like

```
function initialize() {
   //Do your map stuff
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

You should also use https, instead of http, and add the version of the script you want to use, so no surprise in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry but I try your proposition and it's still doesn't work... The script is not load at all... Even if I see it in my dom, if write 'google' in the web console, i was 'google is not defined' !  But with chrome or with the simulator, it works...

Comment: If so,   I have no idea right now. Let me give another look to the code.

Comment: For the I'm using a workaround with OSM for my phone... but if you find a solution, i'm intressting to testing it :)

Comment: I reproduce the problem with the firefox os emulator 1.3